# Inserting custom fields into single.php

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, single

I am trying to get a custom field to show straight after the main body of text in single.php BUT before the Outbrain and Facebook Connect boxes. If I put the line to show the address above `<?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>` then it shows above the body text, if I place it below, it doesn't show at all.

Is there any way to insert it into `'the_content'`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is 'the_content' **filter**. See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).

For instance:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );

/**
 * Add a test to the end of every post page.
 */
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

    if ( is_singular('hotels') ){
        //If a single post is being viewed, add something
        //Or get the value of a custom field and append it
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Address', true);
        $content .= $custom_field_value;
    }
    // Make sure you returns the content, edited or otherwise
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can't get it to work. I must be doing something stupid :)...

I am using a post type where single is single-hotels

And want to add a custom field called 'Address' after the text... How would it fit in?
Thanks

Comment: Replace `is_single()` with `is_singular( 'hotels' )`

Comment: Thanks - I did that but it didnt help

Comment: As TheDeadMedic points out, for custom post type 'customtype', you'll want to use is_singular('customtype'). See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

Comment: @Ben, I have made some changes to answer your question. The above should work, assuming the post is of custom type 'hotels'.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it BUT it still isn;t working... It won't even show the content (if I have the_content in obviously it does work but when I remove the_content, it doesn't show)...

Comment: So, you have the above in you functions.php file? You still need to call: `<?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>` in your template. The above function simply takes the content and adds the custom field to it when it's displayed with `the_content`

Comment: Yeah. I still have it showing after the facebook connect and  outbrain... You can see here for instance: http://www.touristisrael.com/hotels/mount-zion-hotel-2/

Thanks